# How to properly implement POSTPONE in a Forth system?

Tags: forth

John Heyes' ANS Forth test suite contains the following definition:

```
: IFFLOORED [ -3 2 / -2 = INVERT ] LITERAL IF POSTPONE \ THEN ;
```

This is then used to conditionally define various words depending on whether we're using floored or symmetric division:

```
IFFLOORED : T/MOD  >R S>D R> FM/MOD ;
```

So `IFFLOORED` acts like either a noop or a `\` depending on the result of the expression. Fine. That's easily implementable on my threaded interpreter by doing this:

```
: POSTPONE ' , ; IMMEDIATE
```

...and now `IFFLOORED` works; the definition is equivalent to `: IFFLOORED -1 IF ['] \ EXECUTE THEN ;`.

Unfortunately, further down the test suite is the following code:

```
: GT1 123 ;
: GT4 POSTPONE GT1 ; IMMEDIATE
: GT5 GT4 ;
\ assertion here that the stack is empty
```

The same implementation doesn't work here. If `POSTPONE` compiles a reference to its word, then `GT4` becomes the equivalent of `: GT4 123 ;`... but `GT4` is *immediate*. So when `GT5` is defined, 123 is pushed onto the compiler's stack and `GT5` becomes a noop. But that's not right; the test suite expects calling `GT5` to leave 123 on the stack. So for this to work, `POSTPONE` must generate code which generates code:

```
: POSTPONE  ' LITERAL  ['] , LITERAL ;
```

And, indeed, if I play with gForth, I see that `POSTPONE` actually works like this:

```
: GT1 123 ;
: GT4 POSTPONE GT1 ; IMMEDIATE
SEE GT4

<long number> compile, ;
```

But these two definitions are not compatible. If I use the second definition, the first test fails (because now `IFFLOORED` tries to compile `\` rather than executing it). If I use the first definition, the second test fails (because `GT4` pushes onto the compiler stack rather than compiling a literal push).

...but both tests pass in gForth.

So what's going on?

Comment: POSTPONE \ THEN ... pospones a comment. I'm sure that's not what you mean. Could you perhaps fix that listing?

Answer (score 9):

Let me answer here, as the question changed considerably. I am still not sure I understand the question, though :)

In your example, you define

```
: GT4 POSTPONE GT1 ; IMMEDIATE
```

What happens here, is the following:

1. `:` is executed, reading `GT4` and creating the new word
2. `POSTPONE`'s compilation semantics is executed, which is to compile the compilation semantics of `GT1` - as you have seen in GForth.
3. `;` is executed, ending the definition
4. `IMMEDIATE` is executed, marking the last defined word as immediate.

`POSTPONE` is called only when *compiling* `GT4`, and it does not appear in the compiled code. So when later using this immediate word in the definition of `GT5`, the interpretation semantics of `POSTPONE` is not needed.

By the way, according to [the standard](http://forth.sourceforge.net/std/dpans/dpans6.htm#6.1.2033), `POSTPONE` has only compilation semantics, and the interpretation semantics is undefined.

See also the `POSTPONE` tutorial in the [GForth manual](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/POSTPONE-Tutorial.html).

*EDIT* Examples of interpretation and compilation semantics:

```
: TEST1 ." interpretation" ;  => ok
: TEST2 ." compilation" ; IMMEDIATE  => ok
: TEST3 TEST1 TEST2 ;  => compilation ok
TEST3  => interpretation ok
: TEST4 POSTPONE TEST1 ; IMMEDIATE  => ok
: TEST5 TEST4 ;  => ok
TEST5  => interpretation ok
: TEST6 POSTPONE TEST2 ; IMMEDIATE  => ok
TEST6  => compilation ok
```

If you have any more questions, you can reference these tests.

Comment: Yes, I know all that! What I *don't* understand is how `POSTPONE` can work in this case *and* in the `IFFLOORED` case. `GT4` ends up being a word which, when called, *compiles* a call to `GT1`. But `IFFLOORED` ends up being a word which, when called, *executes* a call to \. How can `POSTPONE` do both?

Comment: `POSTPONE` always compiles the compilation semantics of the word. In the case of `GT1`, its compilation semantics is to, well, compile the call to `GT1`. While in the case of \, being an `IMMEDIATE` word, its compilation semantics is to treat the rest of the line as comment. So, essentially, `POSTPONE` postpones the execution of the next word - if it is immediate, then it compiles a simple call to it; if it would be a simple call, then it compiles the code to compile it.

Comment: Oh, it looks to see what kind of word it is! That makes total sense (and once I've done the implementation, it even works). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The snippet you've quoted does the following things:

1. Evaluate -3/2 (at compile time), and check if it is -2.
2. If it is, store a 0 (false), otherwise store a -1 (true) **in** `IFFLOORED`, so when it is evaluated, it will put this value on the stack. (This is the effect of `LITERAL`.)
3. When evaluating `IFFLOORED`, after pushing the value on the stack, comes an `IF` - `THEN` expression. When the value is true, it means that we are *not* in a floored environment, so we want to comment out the rest of the line, and that is what `\` does.

So here comes the tricky part - `\` is `IMMEDIATE`, i.e., you cannot use it inside a colon definition, because it will comment out the rest of the line. You have to explicitly tell the compiler that you want to compile this function, and not execute it, which is what `POSTPONE` does.

Comment: I'm sorry, you've missed the point of my question completely --- I understand how `IFFLOORED` works; it's `POSTPONE` I'm puzzled about. I've updated the question to make it, hopefully, clearer exactly what I want to know.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of [`postpone`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/POSTPONE) word in *compilation state* is to determine compilation semantics for its parsed argument and append these semantics to the current definition.

Compilation semantics for a word can be either special or ordinary (see the section [3.4.3.3 Compilation semantics](https://forth-standard.org/standard/usage#usage:compile) of Forth-2012). To work correctly, `postpone` **should distinguish these cases** and generate code according to the different patterns.

A problem of your implementations is that they are correct either for ordinary compilation semantics or for special compilation semantics.

A standard compliant implementation is as follows:

```
: state-on  ( -- )  1 state ! ;
: state-off ( -- )  0 state ! ;

: execute-compiling ( i*x xt --j*x )
  state @ if  execute  exit  then
  state-on  execute  state-off
;
: postpone ( "name" -- )
  bl word find dup 0= -13 and throw 1 = ( xt flag-special )
  swap lit, if ['] execute-compiling else ['] compile, then compile,
; immediate
```

See more details in my post [How POSTPONE should work](https://github.com/ForthHub/discussion/discussions/105).